# Hidden APIs of Google Chrome / Chromium / Webkit

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am going to develop some apps that are going to specifically target the chrome webstore. 
So the app will only run in chrome.

So I want to make use of all the APIs chromium has to offer. So cross-browser is not an issue here.
This however leads to my question: what are the neat little unknown chromium specific APIs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, Chrome supports a number of open web platform APIs, which are tracked by a few solid resources:

- http://chromestatus.com,
- http://updates.html5rocks.com

Some of these APIs aren't available in other browsers, but there is a web standard behind all of them.

Secondly, there are [Chrome-specific APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html), used by extensions and packaged apps. There is also a list of [experimental APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html) available in the stable release of Chrome. To get a sneak preview, have a look at the [trunk version](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.html) of the experimental APIs, available in the Canary builds.

Note that you'll need to enable experimental extension APIs in your about:flags and restart Chrome before using these, and that you won't be able to deploy them to the webstore until the API is released (not experimental) in the latest stable version of Chrome.